# Что такое lint?

Tags: c, статический-анализ

И что такое: ложное срабатывание lint'a?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> lint

Статический анализатор кода. Проверяет синтаксис и корректность (неинициализированные переменные, например), не запуская компиляцию или выполнение (в зависимости от языка).
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_(software)

> ложное срабатывание lint'a?

Очевидно, указание на ошибку в том месте, где ее нет.

Comment: Спасибо, понял.